# Problem with relative paths(*.bat + VMWARE + Windows 2003)

Tags: windows, batch-file, vmware, relative-path

This may be a question for ServerFault but I was more interested in understanding the methodology that the OS uses to resolve relative paths. I have two VMware instances of Windows 2003. I am trying to run a batch file that starts running another batch file within its folder path. The script runs fine on one VM but on the other VM it fails to execute with the error:

```
>     The System cannot find the file specified
```

The script I am trying to run is `script.bat`:

```
start /d FOLDERNAME /b /WAIT AnotherScript.bat %~n0%~x0
```

I have put both my files within the same folder structure under the C:\ drive on both machines. The file AnotherScript.bat resides within FOLDERNAME on both the VMs.

It is not a permissions issue(?) since I show up as an administrator on both VMs.

I was wondering why would I get an unable to resolve relative paths on one machine vs. the ability to resolve it on another machine.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First check if the folder in which both are lauching are the same. Try adding `ECHO %CD%` before calling the 2nd script to check the directory in which it is getting launched.
2. Also check if the path where the 2nd bat file resides is set in the `%PATH%` variable in the 1st VM.
3. Where does command prompt start by default in both VMs?

Comment: Thanks. Both the scripts are launching from the same directory and the %PATH% variables are the same and the cmd starts from C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe on both machines. None of this seems to be visibly different. Is there something else I should look into?

Comment: @sc_ray I meant the current working directory shown by cmd when you launch it. Also did you try adding ECHO %CD% to your batch script and see what current directory both the VMs are showing before Batch file 2 is executes?